# java web application multiple instance redis session

Tags: java, web, redis, tomcat8, session-management

we have an application which is running on 4 tomcat servers.I would like Redis for session management so that when one of them is down the user should not be facing any problem. I was successfully able to persist the session in redis and was also able to utilise the session in a single instance.

The problem is with multiple instances where I am not able to please kindly help on this

Comment: You need to describe the problem properly.

Comment: I am new to use redis... what I am looking is : In a load balancing environment when a tomcat is stopped the user whose session connected with that server should not disconnect. So what I am trying is using Redis session management storing the session and making the user is not logged out successfully. I was able to do it in a single server environment but not able to do it in a load balancing environment. Please kindly help in what steps to follow